# How to subset dataframe based on two columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have this dataframe:

```
data <- data.frame(
  ID = c(111, 111, 111,111, 333, 333, 333,333),
  planes = c(2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5),
  origin = c(3, 3, 6, 8, 5, 5, 7, 9),
  destination = c(9, 9, 10, 20, 11, 11, 13, 25)
)
```

I want to group the data by ID and planes with the same origin and destination. Planes values 2 and 4 have the same origin and destination and I want to keep them and filter out the rest.

My output should look like this:

```
ID planes origin destination
111     2      3           9
111     2      3           9
333     4      5          11
333     4      5          11
```

Comment: Are you saying you want 3 solutions?

Comment: I fixed that. I want 3 solutions @JonSpring

Comment: What if e.g. origin had 3, 3, 3, 3, and dest 0, 1, 0, 1, this is unclear.

Comment: I want to get a code that always gives me planes with the same origin and destination per ID. I need to apply this to  a dataframe of 100K @jay.sf

Answer (score 3):

You can filter using dplyr

```
data %>% 
   filter(n()>1, .by=everything())
```

We use `by=` to create groups and `n()` then give the number per group so we only keep groups with more than 1 value.

Comment: For a larger dataframe, I might have multiple IDs and planes and I want to get something similar to what you have showed right now.

Comment: Could you check out the updated output

Comment: So in the update you just want to remove the row names? you can use `print(..., row.names=FALSE)` for that. So in the pipe it would be `data %>% filter(n()>1, .by=c(planes, origin, destination)) %>% print(row.names=FALSE)`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a loop for this.

```r
library(dplyr)
data |>
    add_count(planes, ID, destination) |>
    filter(n > 1)
#    ID planes origin destination n
# 1 111      2      3           9 2
# 2 111      2      3           9 2
# 3 333      4      5          11 2
# 4 333      4      5          11 2
```

From the [docs](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/count.html):

> `count()` lets you quickly count the unique values of one or more variables: `df %>% count(a, b)` is roughly equivalent to `df %>% group_by(a, b) %>% summarise(n = n())`.
>
> `add_count()` and `add_tally()` are equivalents to `count()` and `tally()` but use `mutate()` instead of `summarise()` so that they add a new column with group-wise counts.

Comment: I need to group by planes and ID. What if I have multiple IDs and planes

Comment: I am also curious why you didn't add the origin column in this line of code. I want to apply this to a larger dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

You could group both *origin* and *destination* by *ID* and *planes* using `ave` and `subset` for `diff`erences being zero.

```
> subset(data, ave(origin, ID, planes, FUN=diff) == 0 &
+          ave(destination, ID, planes, FUN=diff) == 0)
   ID planes origin destination
1 111      2      3           9
2 111      2      3           9
5 333      4      5          11
6 333      4      5          11
```